# Regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match/sub the following line

```
line1 = '# Some text\n'
```

But avoid match/sub lines like this

```
'# Some text { .blah}\n'
```

So in other a # followed by any amount of words spaces and numbers (no punctuation) and then the end of line.

```
line2 = re.sub(r'# (\P+)$', r'# \1 { .text}', line1)
```

Puts the contents of line1 into line2 unchanged.
(I read somewhere that \P means everything except punctuation)

```
line2 = re.sub(r'# (\w*\d*\s*)+$', r'# \1 { .text}', line1)
```

Whereas the above gives

```
'#  { .text}'
```

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks
Tom

Comment: What is `line1` in `line2 = re.sub(r'# (\P+)$', r'# \1 { .text}', line1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a bit weird; expanded, it looks like

```
r"# ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[0-9]*[ \t\n\r\f\v]*)+$"
```

Things to note:

1. It is not anchored to the beginning of the string, meaning it would match

   ```
   print("Important stuff!")  # Very important
   ```
2. The `\d*` is redundant, because it is already captured by `\w*`
3. Looking at your example, it seems you should be less worried about punctuation; the only thing you cannot have is a curly-brace (`{`).

Try

```
from functools import partial

def add_text(txt):
    return re.sub(r"^#([^{]*)$", r"#\1 { .text }", txt, flags=re.M)

text = "# Some text\n# More text { .blah}\nprint('abc') # but not me!\n# And once again"

print("===before===")
print(text)
print("\n===after===")
print(add_text(text))
```

which gives

```
===before===
# Some text
# More text { .blah}
print('abc') # but not me!
# And once again

===after===
# Some text { .text }
# More text { .blah}
print('abc') # but not me!
# And once again { .text }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added a space (as I don't want it to accept '## Some text'.

re.sub(r"^# ([^{]*)$", r"# \1 { .text }", line, flags=re.M)

Answer (score -1):

If you only want lines which start with a `#` and continue with alphanumeric values, spaces and `_`, you want this:

```
/^#[\w ]+$/gm
```